# Connect MySQL database from Android

Tags: mysql, android

well this is the code snippet i use to access the getUser.php to retrive user details from a MySQL database in my application:

```
String result = "";

    //the year data to send

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid","demo"));

         //http post
         try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.xxx.xx.xxx/getUser.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
                InputStream is = null;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                              ", name: "+json_data.getString("fname")+
                                ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                                ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("dob")
                        );
                }

  }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

}
```

This snippet is taken from http://helloandroid.com

Everything is configured fine: the MySQL Db, IIS with FASTCGi, PHP tools and drivers. even the script below when called from browser with url: http://192.xxx.xx.x.xxx/getUser.php?uid=demo works fine, But returns error in android with **java.lang.NullPointerException** and **org.json.JSONEXCEPTION: End of input at character 0**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("myhost","username","pwd");
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE uid ='".$_REQUEST['uid']."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Can anybody help in this section?

Regards,
Mistry Hardik

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of exceptions, and point out which lines of code they refer to.

Comment: are you running your server on the same system on which emulator is running.

Comment: This tutorial worked for me: http://itweb-projects.com/wordpress/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 1):

You are using the HttpPost Object, which means that are you are initiating a post-request! Are you sure you dont want to do a HttpGet Request?
I ran into the same issue and switching to HttpGet solved my problem!